# How to propery install a third party library from github for a c++ project?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, dependencies, static-libraries

I want to use this library https://github.com/zekyll/OMPEval in my c++ project. I know I must clone the repo and then use make to compile the files. However, I don't know which directory to place it in order for it to function how the author demonstrated. The authors example:

```
#include <omp/HandEvaluator.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace omp;
int main()
{
    HandEvaluator eval;
    Hand h = Hand::empty(); // Final hand must include empty() exactly once!
    h += Hand(51) + Hand(48) + Hand(0) + Hand(1) + Hand(2); // AdAs2s2h2c
    std::cout << eval.evaluate(h) << std::endl; // 28684 = 7 * 4096 + 12
}
```

How can I use the library as demonstrated?

Answer (score 4):

That's going to depend on how you compile your project, if you use Visual Studio, then you can simply add the `.lib` files to the linker settings in the project settings, and add the `include` directory to your `additional include directories`

If you use GCC/Clang or another compiler directly, you'll have to explicitly pass the arguments to the compiler,

`clang++ main.cpp -I./path/to/include -llibrary_file`

You can set the path to library files using `-L./....`

Since your question is marked `ubuntu`, you can usually install libraries through `apt` but it doesn't seem like OMPEval has an apt repository.

EDIT:
Please note the `./` in both the `-L` and `-I` flag are RELATIVE paths, remove the `.` and you have an absolute path

Comment: You may want to clarify `-I./`. The dot suggests you are suggesting relative paths rooted from the working directory and this is probably incorrect. The rest of this is pretty much bang on, So probably just a typo.

Comment: It wasn't that much of a type, but I assumed he knew it was relative, My include directories for my own projects are always relative to my project, so where my source is in `src`, my includes will be in `/include`, but yeah, ill edit it real quick